# How to implement a priority queue using the field of a class in java

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a java class called `MeterReading` with two fields `String MeterName` and `int MeterLevel`.

Now, if the `MeterLevel` is between 0 and 3, that is Low, when between 3 and 6, Medium and from 6 above is High. How would I pass in that class `MeterReading` to a priority queue? Is this possible?

Comment: do you want to sort by meterLevel or by Low/Medium/High?  You pass the reading to the queue by calling `q.add(reading);`  but first you have to define how you want to compare them.

Comment: It's possible. Create flags and pass the data as needed using getters and boolean to your priority queue. Please show your work. Additional [Information](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_priorityqueue.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implements `Comparable` interface of your class. The trick is adding a method to get the `levelClass` (LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH) that is used in the `compareTo` method.

```
public class MeterReading implements Comparable {
    public static final int LOW = 0;
    public static final int MEDIUM = 1;
    public static final int HIGH = 2;

    private String name;
    private double level;

    ... // Constructor, getter setter and business logic methods

    public int getLevelClass() {
        if (level < 3) {
            return LOW;
        } else if (level < 6) {
            return MEDIUM;
        } else {
            return HIGH;
        }
    }

    public int compareTo(MeterReading m2) {
        return getLevelClass() - m2.getLevelClass();
    }
}
```

The implementation of `compareTo` can be also the following if you need the opposite priority.

```
public int compareTo(MeterReading m2) {
    return m2.getLevelClass() - getLevelClass();
}
```

To add a `MeterReading` to a `PriorityQueue` only add it

```
MeterReading mr = ....;
PriorityQueue pq = ....;
....
pq.add(mr);
```

Comment: how would you then pass the meterReading class into the priority queue?

Comment: I want to see how I could add any number of meterReading objects to the priority. Would the code be this:
PriorityQueue<myOwnComparatorClasss> queue = new PriorityQueue<myOwnComparatorClasss>();
queue.add(mr) 
?

Comment: In this case is PriorityQueue<MeterReading> queue = new PriorityQueue<MeterReading>(); queue.add(mr); where mr is an Object of type MeterReading